# how do you capture process-specific loopback interface network traffic on OSX?

Tags: macos, process, tcpdump, loopback, network-monitoring

I would like to monitor traffic between two processes running on OSX El Capitan. The server is listening on 127.0.0.1 so i believe i need to monitor the lo0 loopback interface.

I'm trying to use the tcpdump program supplied by Apple to do this with the following command, as per https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/tcpdump.1.html:

```
sudo tcpdump -i pktap,lo0 -v ./DumpFile01.pcap
```

but this fails with:

```
tcpdump: data link type PKTAP
tcpdump: listening on pktap,lo0, link-type PKTAP (Packet Tap), capture size 262144 bytes
tcpdump: pktap_filter_packet: pcap_add_if_info(lo0, 0) failed: pcap_add_if_info: pcap_compile_nopcap() failed
```

It appears to be Apple's version of tcpdump:

```
tcpdump --version
tcpdump version 4.7.3 -- Apple version 66
libpcap version 1.5.3 - Apple version 54
```

From the tcpdump man page above and https://dreness.com/blog/archives/829 i think i should be able to run the following to see the packets for a given process:

```
tcpdump -i pktap,lo0 -Q "proc =myserver"
```

Has anybody had success with this? I would try the latest tcpdump, but i understand from the man page that "-Q" is an Apple extension.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> `sudo tcpdump -i pktap,lo0 -v ./DumpFile01.pcap`

That tcpdump command says "capture on `lo0` with pktap, print text output in verbose mode, and use the string "./DumpFile01.pcap" as a capture filter".  `-v` means "print in verbose mode"; did you mean `-w`, which means "write in binary form to the file whose name comes after the `-w` flag"?

"./DumpFile01.pcap" is not a valid capture filter; unfortunately, Apple's libpcap is buggy (Apple bug 21698116), and, if you're capturing with pktap, its error message for invalid capture filters is the not-very-informative "pktap_filter_packet: pcap_add_if_info(lo0, 0) failed: pcap_add_if_info: pcap_compile_nopcap() failed".  (I told them how to fix it in the bug; hopefully they'll fix it in 10.12 Big Sur or whatever it's called, even if they don't get around to fixing it in 10.11.x.)

If you want to monitor traffic on `lo0`, and have tcpdump *print its interpretation* of the traffic on the terminal (rather than saving it to a binary pcap file for later interpretation by tcpdump or Wireshark or whatever; neither tcpdump nor Wireshark can read, as a capture, printed output from tcpdump), then do

```
sudo tcpdump -i pktap,lo0 -v
```

If you want the printed interpretation saved to a text file (again, you *cannot* feed that text file to tcpdump or Wireshark as a capture), do

```
sudo tcpdump -i pktap,lo0 -v >PrintedCapture.txt
```

If you want to save the *raw* packet data to a *binary* capture file for later interpretation by tcpdump or Wireshark or whatever, do:

```
sudo tcpdump -i pktap,lo0 -w ./DumpFile01.pcap
```

(`-w`, *not* `-v`).

And, yes, `-Q` is an Apple extension.  `-k` is another Apple extension to print packet metadata such as process names if you're capturing with pktap.

Comment: Thanks for your help, Guy. This works for me, using your suggestion: `sudo tcpdump -i pktap,lo0 -Q "proc =myserver" -k -v -w ./DumpFile01.pcap`

Comment: Neither `-k` nor `-v` make any difference in that command line; they both affect what tcpdump *prints* when it's producing a text dissection of the packets, but, with `-w`, it just writes raw packet data, without any interpretation, to the file.

Comment: I see.. thanks. As you can probably tell, i'm in 'get something to work' mode :).